# Representing a chain of nodes in a human readable way

Tags: c#, tree, structure, recursive-datastructures

I'm trying to represent a subway map type thing that has to be drawn progressively (like its growing).

My code all works perfectly but its unreadable. Basically it's a tree structure with recursive nodes and subnodes and my test code looks like this:

```
        Children.Add(new TrackLine(800));
        Children[0].Children.Add(new TrackSpot());
        Children[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new TrackSplitter());

        Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new TrackRotate(-45));
        Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new TrackColorChange(Color.Red));
        Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new TrackLine(100));
        Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new TrackRotate(45));
        Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children[0].Children.Add(new TrackLine(200));
```

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to fix that mess?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a way to add it to the deepest child that has no children of it's own?

```
class Node
{
  List<Node> children ;

  public void addNode( Node newNode )
  {
    if( children.Count > 0 )
      children[0].addNode( newNode ) ; // recursive call
      // to ask first child to add newNode to it
    else
      children.Add( newNode ) ;        // just add it to the children list of THIS node
  }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you choose this over TreeNode?

Comment: If he really wants to use that "do it yourself" mentality?? (Admittedly not a C# guru?)

Comment: You guys didn't notice the stray semicolon at the end of the class def ;)

Comment: That's a great idea but unfortunately it's a tree and not a basic chain so it has to branch in various places.

Answer (score 0):

To make that code more readable I'd use variables with appropriate names (since I don't know your subject domain, mine are probably not appropriate):

```
Children.Add(new TrackLine(800));
var lineA = Children[0];

lineA.Children.Add(new TrackSpot());
var spotA = lineA.Children[0];

spotA.Children.Add(new TrackSplitter());
var splitterA = spotA.Children[0];

splitterA.Children.Add(new TrackRotate(-45));
var rotateNeg45 = splitterA.Children[0];

rotateNeg45.Children.Add(new TrackColorChange(Color.Red));
var colorRed = rotateNeg45.Children[0];

colorRed.Add(new TrackLine(100));
var lineB = colorRed.Children[0];

lineB.Children.Add(new TrackRotate(45));
var rotatePos45 = lineB.Children[0];

rotatePos45.Children.Add(new TrackLine(200));
var lineC = rotatePos45.Children[0];
```

Another approach is to use strings as indexes for `Children` like this:

```
    Children.Add(new TrackLine(800));
    Children["lineA"].Children.Add(new TrackSpot());
    Children["lineA"].Children["spotA"].Children.Add(new TrackSplitter());
```

However I probably would not do it because managing the string constants would be a mess on its own and it would probably require changing `Children` implementation.